# Subclassing and typing in scala

Tags: scala, types

I am having trouble properly typing in Scala -- I want to do something like this, imposing Ordered on a class hierarchy, but with the subclasses allowing the compare method to only work with parameters of their own type

```
abstract class Parent extends Ordered
class A extends Parent {
  override def compare(that : A) = 1
}
class B extends Parent {
  override def compare(that : B) = 1
}
```

The following works, but then I am forced, forever, to impose type specificity on Parent and its subclasses forever.  This just becomes a nightmare to reason about correctly.

```
abstract class Parent[T <: Parent[_]] extends Ordered[T]
class A extends Parent[A] {
  override def compare(that : A) = 1
}
class B extends Parent[A] {
  override def compare(that : B) = 1
}
```

Is there a simpler method to mandate a type on subclasses of Ordered[T] ?

Comment: If we had `ThisType` you'd perhaps have been able to write `abstract class Parent { this: Ordered[ThisType] => /* */ }`.

Comment: If objects of (non-generic) class `A` admits comparison with other objects of class `A`, then, by definition, objects of all subclasses of `A` admit comparison with objects *of class `A`*, and not just with their own kind.

Comment: You don't want a subclass.  A subclass has every capability that the parent has _and more_.  (This is the "Liskov substitution principle" at work.)  Any design that relies upon doing this backwards is likely to be full of problems--it certainly is not theoretically sound.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just

```
abstract class Parent
class A extends Parent with Ordered[A] {...}
class B extends Parent with Ordered[B] {...}
```

As others have pointed out, according to your comparison criteria, a sequence of `Parent`s would not be ordered, because its subclasses are not comparable. Only its subclasses are `Ordered`, so implement the trait there.

Answer (score 1):

I agree this problem is a bit annoying, but it would be a little strange if the behavior you're looking for was allowed. Supposing you did

```
trait Parent {
    this: Ordered[ThisType]
}

// Does A need to be Ordered[A]?
trait A extends Parent

// Should B, C be comparable? If A is Ordered, then they
// have to be. But is this what you want?
class B extends A
class C extends A

// Now what?
class D extends B
```

Basically, it would be a little odd to use inheritance to force some property like this... it could probably be made to work in theory, but it would be a departure from what inheritance is meant for. Instead, you could specify the `Ordered` constraint in methods when you need it:

```
def foo[T <: Ordered[T]](x: T) = ...
```

Or, if you want to group the `Ordered` constraint and possible others under a common name, you could make a typeclass-style trait:

```
trait Parent[A] {
    val order: Ordering[A]
}

def foo[T : Parent](x: T, y: T) {
    println(implicitly[Parent[T]].order.compare(x, y))
}
```

An unfortunate aspect of this solution is that you cannot specify `sealed`; I'd be interested if anyone has a way around that. Otherwise, you could use a dependently typed programming language, they're a little better at this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Luigi, I think that is the right answer.  I think I am approaching this from a Java OO paradigm, where it is common to have a need to order a group of Parents without knowledge of their underlying type.  At least in my little setting, it is beginning to dawn on me that if I set up my functional approach correctly, I *will* know the type of the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks that's a very good insight --- never thought about that before.  I just lit on this as a solution but frankly it seems a little smelly and it makes me a little nervous.  Comments?

```
abstract class Parent extends Ordered[Parent] {
  override def compare(that : Parent) : Int = {
    (this, that) match {
      case (x : A, y : A) =>  x.compare(y)
      case (x : B, y : B) =>  x.compare(y)
      case _ =>  throw new ClassCastException
    }
  }
}
class A extends Parent {
  def compare(that : A) = 1
}
class B extends Parent {
  def compare(that : B) = 1
}
```

Comment: That would work, though you lose the ability to check that it's safe at compile time. That's a lot to lose, IMO.

Comment: Though, in terms of the structure of your code, it's not atypical for functional programming; whether it's good or not I'm not sure. It's just you lose type safety, which isn't so great.